# What's %g and %e format?

Tags: c, format

I want to know what's `%g` and `%e` format. What do they mean?

Comment: It should all be explained in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf#Parameters).

Comment: [Standard C11 documentation for `fprintf()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1): the exact same specifiers apply to `printf()`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you question refers to the string formatting syntax like it is used e. g. in printf("%g", 1.0). %g is the shortest representation of a number, and %e is the scientific number representation with the exponent in lower case.

More information about this syntax can be found here: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/